# Excel Spreadsheet formula help| selected currency AND role shows a specific day rate

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm desperately trying to work out the formula for a project pricing tool i'm working on with my team.

We cost jobs in multiple currencies, and each role has a different rate based on the currency.

In my costing tool i have a dropdown for currency, let's use Pounds and EURO for now.

Then in my costing table (same sheet) i have dropdowns on each line item (row) that allows me to enter the role that will handle that tasks.

[image: example table]

So in cell i1 is a drop down with currency (€,£)
In column H is a drop down for role.

Based on the selection in column H i want to return either the € or £ rate is columns d or e respectively.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you.

Comment: Check out this [site with video](https://www.contextures.com/excelconditionalformatcurrency.html) on how to use conditional formatting to change the currency.

Comment: Thanks Peter, but it's not about simply formatting the cell, its that we have different rates depending on which currency we bill in (its not a direct currency converssion but a fixed amount)

So a developer might be £100 per hour but if charging in Euros we would charge them at 120 EURO per hour.

Comment: I'd setup a table with currencies and an index number. Per your example EUR = 2 GBP = 3. Then you could do a look up of the currency and retrieve the index to use in a lookup of the Role to return the rate.

Comment: @RetiredGeek would you be able to help me with the formula for that?

Comment: When you get answers, you should decide and mark them as answers. Your question shows no work of your own and you are using other people's time and experience as a free service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is only two currencies, then:

```
=LOOKUP( H4, $C$6:$C$13, IF( I1 = "EURO", $D$6:$D$13, $E$6:$E$13))
```

[image]

If more than two currencies, then use an INDEX MATCH, but your I1 needs to match the currency column headers.  For example:

```
=INDEX( $D$6:$F$13, MATCH( H4, $C$6:$C$13, 0 ), MATCH( $I$1, $D$5:$F$5, 0 ) )
```

[image]

Comment: This index match one worked mark thank you.

Comment: Hi @LouFranklin - ok, good. As RetiredGeek said, you should accept one of these by clicking the check mark to the left. It's otherwise uncool to get answers and leave them unacknowledged (which, frankly happens a lot).

Answer (score 0):

Lou,

Ok, here's a mockup.
[image]
You'll notice that I used Range names for the tables (see bottom of sheet).
The formula shown in the formula bar is in I4 and is dragable down the column.
The formula uses two VLookups the inner one to retrieve the currency column offset for use in the outer one that looks up the role.

Note: the items under Role must exactly match those in Col A so I suggest doing copy/paste operations.

Comment: Amazing thank you so much this is really helpful!!!! @retiredGeek

Comment: @LouFranklin if you're happy with the solution please mark it as accepted by clicking the check mark to the left.

Comment: Actually the nested vlookups were causing me a lot of trouble i think something to do with the names within my drop down. I could see it was pulling from the right columns for budget BUT it was n't running in order like the roles were. It worked for role 1 and 2, but then role three was displaying role 9's rate. I think something do do with the role names being similar both starting with 'Creative' .

in the end the one that worked for me was:

=INDEX( $D$6:$F$13, MATCH( H4, $C$6:$C$13, 0 ), MATCH( $I$1, $D$5:$F$5, 0 ) )